# Master page code and Page source code differ

Tags: master-page, web, system-master-page

Good day.
I was wondering why the master page code I have added to a header will show correctly, but when looking at the web page source, it is commented out.

**SharePoint Master page view:**
[image]

**Web Source Page view:**
[image]